# Android/Java: Time calculations

Tags: java, android, time

Im using the following code in my android app to get the current time

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String time =  dateFormatLocal.format(new Date());
```

I would like to know if theres an easy way to check timespans, for example if the clock is between 19:00 and 21:00. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with Chris's method, but here's another option:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
if (hour >= 19  &&  hour < 21) {
    System.out.println("WIN");
}
```

Then you can construct your string with:

```
String time =  dateFormatLocal.format(now.getTime() );
```

I'll leave it to the next poster to point out that you can also use Joda-Time. :)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most efficient solution (as I think you could probably do it with the Date objects) but what about

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
String hours = df.format(new Date());
Integer number = Integer.parseInt(hours);
if (numbers >= 19 && numbers <= 20){
 //good
}else{
  //not good
}
```